# BIRT installation fail

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, birt

I have Eclipse Luna installed and I want to install and use BIRT. I have followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RnbX3h7vN7E) tutorial and downloaded the archive from there. After I dearchived the .zip file I have [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reIsR.png) and when I am trying to run the `BIRT.exe` file it shows me [this message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPhX6.png).

What should I do?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like your Birt is 32 bit and your Java is 64 bit. They must both be 32 bit or both 64 bit.

Comment: I have downloaded it from http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/. But it is only one version of RCP Designer, it doesn't say if it is 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: The message is absolutely clear - it is a 32 bit RCP so it needs a 32 bit Java.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the version of the BIRT is a 32-bit one and what I need is a 64-bit. So that's why it doesn't work in this case.